# Null value when creating list in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, vector

I am using the following code to store the result of a `for` loop in a variable:

```
> fileExist
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

for (i in seq_along(fileExist)){

  if (fileExist[[i]]=='TRUE'){
    index4<-vector('list', length(fileExist))
    index4[[i]]<-i
  }
}
```

The output is giving me a wrong result in `index[[1]]`

```
> index4
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

What I want to achive is:
- Having the `fileExist` variable which can be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, 
- I want to store in another variable the position (index) of the `TRUE` in the `fileExist` variable

So if `fileExist` is `[[1]] TRUE` and `[[2]] TRUE` I should get something like

```
> index4
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

If `fileExist` is `[[1]] FALSE` and `[[2]] TRUE` I should get something like

```
> index4
[[1]]
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the index, `unlist` and wrap with `which`

```
as.list(which(unlist(fileExist)))
```

Comment: Perfect solution, I was complicating it too much